# What version of Alpine Linux OS to install on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, linux

I want to install Alpine Linux on Raspberry Pi 3. There are two versions of **armhf** and **aarch64** on the [download page](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/). Which one should I choose?

Comment: Either should work on a RPi3. Do you want 32bit or 64bit

Comment: whichever works better. Aarch64 is often less well supported, but info is scarce.

Comment: @Dougie I want to use 64bit

Comment: aarch64 would be the 64bit version - the armhf would definitely be 32bit, because it does mention pi1 and pi2 which are not 64 bit